# Ajax Control Toolkit: FSharp.Core Error

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've experiencing some troubles when running applications in Visual Web Developer 2010 with the Ajax Control Toolkit (ToolkitScriptManager).

Many times an error occours when I run the solution:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. 
O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
(System couldn't find the specified file).
```

If I choose "Continue", I must to reload the webpage and then the page seems to work, despite with the ajax controls (accordion) not properly rendered (I think).

Error shown in webpage (localhost asp.net development server):

```
Line 13: <body>
Line 14:     <form id="form1" runat="server">
Line 15:     <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
Line 16:     </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
Line 17:
```

I even added the FSharp installation in visual studio 2010, but nothing changes. This problem occours also in IIS, where I deploy the site.

It's a test page, there is only the toolkitscriptmanager and an accordion control.

Features: Visual Web Developer 2010 version 10.0.30319.1, .NET 4.0.30319 RTMRel, Ajax Control Toolkit 3.5.40412.0 (Also IIS 7.5.7600.16385).

What's going on? Where can I find FSharp.Core (or register it) and why, sometimes, the system don't ask me for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution for this problem:

[Could not load file or assembly FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042253/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-fsharp-core-version-4-0-0-0)

Installing the redist (F# runtime) on the deployment machine solved the problem for me.