# How to update FSharp.Core for Visual Studio 2012 fsi

Tags: visual-studio-2012, f#, f#-interactive

I am trying to run a script in the fsi. I get the following error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I found the following references that suggest I may have to update the default FSharp.Core version somewhere inside Visual Studio, downloading the package with nuget is not enough.

- [Correct version of Fsharp.Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332046/correct-version-of-fsharp-core)
- [Could not load file or assembly FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042253/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-fsharp-core-version-4-0-0-0)
- [How to use FSharp.Core 4.3.0 when all you have is 4.3.1](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/01/30/how-to-use-fsharpcore-430-when-all-you-have-is-431/)

I am not sure how to fix this and I am afraid to permanently damage the vs configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see where FSI is located by typing

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;;
```

In my computer I get

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\

And I have a file

> Fsi.exe.config

which does the redirects.

You probably point to an old FSharp installation, as 4.3.0.0 and 4.3.1.0 should be binary compatible.

Comment: Thanks. After restarting VS, the script now executes but IntelliSense still doesn't work properly.

Comment: oh there is no intellisense in fsi if that is what you refer to. the way to use it is to type your script in fsx file, in the editor, then hightlight and alt + enter. that sends the text area in FSI

Comment: Yes, I know, thanks. Sorry, my question got messy with the latest edit. Now the script runs properly in the fsi but  IntelliSense in the Visual Studio editor, where I type my script, is not working.

Comment: I have reverted back to the old version of my question.. the updated edit was confusing at most.